# Extract words from a comma separated string in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, csv

Suppose I have string

```
Str = 'Aaa,Bbb,Abb,Ccc'
```

I want to separate the above str in two parts as follows

```
Str1 = 'Aaa,Abb'

Str2 = 'Bbb,Ccc'
```

That is any word in str starting with A should go in str1 rest all in str2.

How can I achieve this using Oracle queries?

Comment: Never ever store data as comma separated items. That will only cause you lots of problems. SQL isn't designed for that, have separate rows instead.

Comment: An addition to @jarlh's comment- you can use nested tables or other collection types.

Answer (score 3):

> That is any word in str starting with A should go in str1 rest all in str2.

To achieve it in pure **SQL**, I will use the following:

- **REGEXP_SUBSTR**
- **LISTAGG**
- **SUBSTR**
- **INLINE VIEW**

So, first I will split the comma delimited string using the techniques as demonstrated here [Split single comma delimited string into rows](http://lalitkumarb.wordpress.com/2014/12/02/split-comma-delimited-string-into-rows-using-oracle-sql/).

And then, I will aggregate them using **LISTAGG** in an order.

For example,

```
SQL> WITH
  2  t1 AS (
  3  SELECT 'Aaa,Bbb,Abb,Ccc' str FROM dual
  4        ),
  5  t2 AS (
  6  SELECT trim(regexp_substr(str, '[^,]+', 1, LEVEL)) str
  7    FROM t1
  8  CONNECT BY LEVEL <= regexp_count(str, ',')+1
  9  ORDER BY str
 10        )
 11  SELECT
 12    (SELECT listagg(str, ',') WITHIN GROUP(
 13    ORDER BY NULL) str1
 14    FROM t2
 15    WHERE SUBSTR(str, 1, 1)='A'
 16    ) str1,
 17    (SELECT listagg(str, ',') WITHIN GROUP(
 18    ORDER BY NULL) str
 19    FROM t2
 20    WHERE SUBSTR(str, 1, 1)<>'A'
 21    ) str2
 22  FROM dual
 23  /

STR1       STR2
---------- ----------
Aaa,Abb    Bbb,Ccc

SQL>
```

The **WITH** clause is just for demonstration purpose, in your real scenario, remove the with clause and use you table name directly. Though it looks neat using the WITH clause.

Answer (score 0):

Use regext expression and ListAg function.

**NOTE**: LISTAGG function is available since Oracle 11g!

```
select listagg(s.name, ',') within group (order by name)
  from (select regexp_substr('Aaa,Bbb,Abb,Ccc,Add,Ddd','[^,]+', 1, level) name from dual
       connect by regexp_substr('Aaa,Bbb,Abb,Ccc,Add,Ddd', '[^,]+', 1, level) is not null) s
group by decode(substr(name,1,1),'A', 1, 0);
```

Comment: OP wants in two different columns.

Answer (score 0):

This query gives you the desired output in two different rows:

```
with temp as (select trim (both ',' from 'Aaa,Bbb,Abb,Ccc') as str from dual),
     base_table as
         (    select trim (regexp_substr (t.str,
                                          '[^' || ',' || ']+',
                                          1,
                                          level))
                         str
                from temp t
          connect by instr (str,
                            ',',
                            1,
                            level - 1) > 0),
     ult_table as
         (select str,
                 case upper (substr (str, 1, 1)) when 'A' then 1 else 2 end
                     as l
            from base_table)
select listagg (case when l = 1 then str else null end, ',')
           within group (order by str)
           str1,
       listagg (case when l = 2 then str else null end, ',')
           within group (order by str)
           str2
  from ult_table;
```

**Output**

```
         L STR
---------- --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
         1 Aaa,Abb                                                                         
         2 Bbb,Ccc
```

Comment: OP wants in two different columns.

Comment: @LalitKumarB- thanks for noting that. Edited the code.